# Set up of Web API with SPA redirection in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API running on .NET 7 set up with an SPA being served by Vite:

```cs
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:5173");
        });
}
```

This mostly works. However, when I have an exception in my code, which currently seems to be all the time, it seems that this exception is caught and then control is passed to Vite, which, obviously, will have no idea what to do with it.  Here I get a 404 not-found return, which is not as helpful as I'd like.

I would like to tell the system to try the normal controller routing first, and, if one is found, do not fall back to the SPA proxy behaviour, but, instead, use the developer exception page (in development mode).  This will make it much easier to diagnose all the various bugs I'm likely to introduce.  Commenting out the Spa redirect makes it harder to test from within the SPA, but then tells me the error.

Is there a way to configure this during application setup?

Comment: Could you please share which version of asp.net core you are using? When 404 has been encountered? Which route its been redirected to what causing 404, could you tell the details?

Comment: I'm running .NET 7 on Linux. I'll have to update a more precise version when I'm home.  The 404 is when I try to use a controller/endpoint in C#, but it throws an exception, and then retries with the proxy.  If I turn off (comment out) the proxy, then I get the exception being displayed instead which is what I want, except I still need the proxy.

Comment: Thanks for your response, could you please share what you are getting in the exception stracktrace?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron the stack trace I'm getting is because I have bugs in my code. I don't think it's relevant other than it's being hidden. I want the stack trace of my own bugs to display, not be hidden by being redirected to the proxy instead. Eventually I'll fix all the bugs and there will be no stack trace, and it will just work.  But then I'll introduce a new bug and get a 404 instead of a stack trace, and it'll be just as annoying.

Comment: I opted to go with the reverse: have vite proxy to kestrel, and remove the SPA redirect in C#.